# Show value to HTML just like how value gets display in CMD prompt when executes print() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, speech-recognition

I am working on speech recognition by following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/) and implementing in Django. I'm wondering the way we execute `print("Listening...")` and `print("Recognizing...")` for user to understand when to speak in CMD prompt, is it possible to send value (Listening, Recognizing) in HTML page each time when user speaks something ?

```
def takeCommand(): 
    r = sr.Recognizer() 
    with sr.Microphone() as source:  
        print("Listening...") 
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print(audio)
    try: 
        print("Recognizing...")     
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in') 
        print("User said:",query) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)     
        print("Unable to Recognizing your voice.")
        return "None"
    return query
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `django.contrib.messages` to "print" them to the template.

In your view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.warning(self.request, f'Unable to Recognizing your voice')
```

In your template:

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

For more info about the messages framework see the: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: Thank you but `NameError : 'self' is not defined.` Is what the error I'm getting. I have implemented `messages.warning(self.request, f'Unable to Recognizing your voice')` in takeCommand() function. If I provide the `request` parameter on takeCommand() then it's creating problem where I'm using this function. Please let me know the soution.

Comment: I think you can just change "self.request" to "request" and also add request to your function: "def takeCommand(request):"

Answer (score 0):

how do you send the audio to the server? somehow via ajax?
When he clicks a button to start talking, you use JS/jquery to put somewhere:
`$('#some_div').append('Listening...');`
When he stops talking, you put there:
`$('#some_div').append('Recognizing...');`
And you send the audio via ajax to the server.
Then you response from the server to the ajax request and do either:
`$('#some_div').append('Unable to Recognizing your voice.');`
or:
`$('#some_div').append('User said: ' + response.query);`